# Why wordpress doesn't generate thumbnails?

Tags: post-thumbnails, thumbnails

Wordpress doesn't generate thumbnails in my server. I don't know why. Old images' thumbnails get regenerated; however, the newly uploaded ones doesn't. I used Regenerate Thumbnails plugin to regenerate all the thumbnails. The new ones doesn't regenerate. It gives me error "The error message was: Unknown failure reason."

I have checked everything. I have GD enabled in php.ini and the directory is writable. What else should I check?

Comment: What happens if you disable all plugins, activate a default WP theme. Then upload an image?

Comment: I'll check it now

Comment: didn't work. I am going to check the PHP logs

Comment: May be something is up with server and php settings. Check error logs.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. For some reason it was a JPEG file's issue. I recreated all the JPEGs and now it generates the thumbnails...